# How to cap framerate to 60fps in QT opengl

Tags: opengl, qtopengl

I used to cap the render framerate in GLFW using  the function.

```
glfwSwapInterval(1);
```

Now i am building a Opengl project in QT using the Qt opengl features.

in the main function i set the global value.

```
QGLFormat  format;
    format.setDepthBufferSize(24);
    format.setStencilBufferSize(8);
    format.setSampleBuffers(true);
    format.setSamples(4);
    format.setSwapInterval(1);
    QGLFormat::setDefaultFormat(format);
```

This is how the Qt opengl class header looks like.

```
   class GLWidget : public  QGLWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT;
public:
    explicit GLWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    void initializeGL() override;
    void paintGL() override;
    void resizeGL(int w, int h) override;
    QTimer timer;

};
```

In the constructor for the class

```
 GLWidget::GLWidget(QWidget *parent) :QGLWidget(parent)
{
    connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, [&]() {  
        QElapsedTimer elapsedtimer;
        elapsedtimer.start();
        updateGL();
        qDebug() << elapsedtimer.elapsed();
    });
    timer.setInterval(0);
    timer.start();
}
```

But still the render loop is not synced the Qdebug values keeps varying from 8 to 16.

Comment: See [`QGLFormat::setSwapInterval`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qglformat.html#setSwapInterval).  Note, however, that [`QGLWidget` is obsolete](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qglwidget.html).  Assuming you're using Qt5 you should consider using [`QOpenGLWidget`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglwidget.html) instead.

Comment: @G.M thanks for your reply , i have updated the question based on your input but still the render loop is not synced.

Comment: The code shown works for me -- `paintGL` is invoked at a rate of 60Hz.  Are you sure you're not confusing the rate rate at which `updateGL` is called rather than `paintGL`?  They're not the same thing.

Comment: @G.M The debug output varies from " qDebug() << elapsedtimer.elapsed();"  9 to 16 does not stay at constant rate.

Comment: @G.M i might  be confusing the difference between updateGL and paintGL , how can i calculate the frame rate of paintGL ?

Comment: As a starting point, put a `qDebug` statement in your `paintGL` implementation that outputs the current frame number and timestamp.